# Disable VERTICAL Scroll only

Tags: javascript, wordpress, scroll, overflow, elementor

Bonjour amis développeur ! ,

Since yesterday i'm blocking to block a vertical scrolling of my site but just the vertical, i create a slider with parallax effect and i need to Scroll horizontaly
Without Wordpress in a simple HTML / CSS / JS is good but when i integrated in Wordpress the scroll (With the mousse)  doesn't :( !

[The Scroll bar is here but 0 Scroll with mousse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwTaw.png)

I'm Share my code, if you have a idea to disable Scroll vertical and Active horizontale you save me ! :p

A French studend, Antoine see u !!

```js
let slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
let sliderWidth;
let imageWidth;
let current = 0;
let target = 0;
let ease = .05;
let images = [...document.querySelectorAll('.img')];

images.forEach((img, idx) => {
    img.style.backgroundImage = `url(https://www.industrialempathy.com/img/remote/ZiClJf-1920w.jpg)`
})


    function lerp(start, end, t) {
        return start * (1 - t) + end * t;
    }

    function setTransform(el, transform) {
        el.style.transform = transform;
    }

    function init() {
        sliderWidth = slider.getBoundingClientRect().width;
        imageWidth = sliderWidth / images.length;
        document.body.style.height = `${sliderWidth - (window.innerWidth - window.innerHeight)}px`
    }

    function animate() {
        current = parseFloat(lerp(current, target, ease)).toFixed(2);
        target = window.scrollY;
        setTransform(slider, `translateY(-${current}px)`)
        animatedImage();
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

    function animatedImage() {
        let ratio = current / imageWidth;
        let RatioValue;

        images.forEach((image) => {
            RatioValue = ratio - (0.2);
            setTransform(image, `translateX(-${RatioValue * 20}px)`)

        })
    }


    init();

    animate();
```

```css
@media (min-width: 800px) {
    body{
        background-color: #F2F2F2;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        overflow-x:scroll;
        overflow-y: hidden;


    }

    main {
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
    }

    .slider {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 3400px;
        height: 68%;
    }

    .slider-inner {
        position: fixed;
        top: 15%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }

    .item {
        position: relative;
        width: 400px;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding-top: 6%;
    }

    .img {
        position: absolute;
        width: 500px;
        height: 100%;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;

    }
    .title  {

        background-color: #F2F2F2;
        text-align:center ;
        padding: 12px;

    }

    .link {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #053D21 ;
    }
    .link:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #EA734E ;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 801px) {
    .title  {
        background-color: #F2F2F2;
        text-align:center ;
        padding-top: 12px;
        padding-bottom: 12px;
        margin-bottom: 15%;
        width:100%;
    }

    body{
        background-color: #F2F2F2;
        margin: 0 ;



    }

    main {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }

    .slider-inner {
        display: block;

        justify-content: center;
    }

    .slider {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;

    }

    .item {

        border: solid 2px brown;
        width:90%;
        height: 20%;
    }

    .img {

        width:95%;
        height: 100%;
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    .slider-inner {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }


    .link {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #053D21 ;
    }
    .link:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #EA734E ;
    }




}
```

```html
  <main>
    <div class="slider" align="center" >
        <div class="slider-inner">

                <a href="#" class="link">
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="img" ></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="title"><h2>Ma super vidéo</h2></div>
                </a>



            <section>
                <a href="#" class="link">
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="img" ></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="title"><h2>Ma super vidéo</h2></div>
                </a>
            </section>

            <section>
                <a href="#" class="link">
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="img" ></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="title"><h2>Ma super vidéo</h2></div>
                </a>
            </section>

            <section>
                <a href="#" class="link">
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="img" ></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="title"><h2>Ma super vidéo</h2></div>
                </a>
            </section>

            <section>
                <a href="#" class="link">
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="img" ></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="title"><h2>Ma super vidéo</h2></div>
                </a>
            </section>

            <section>
                <a href="#" class="link">
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="img" ></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="title"><h2>Ma super vidéo</h2></div>
                </a>
            </section>

            <section>
                <a href="#" class="link">
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="img" ></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="title"><h2>Ma super vidéo</h2></div>
                </a>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

</main>
```

Comment: If you don't want a vertical scrollbar, you can add `overflow-y:hidden` to your css. However, it's not that clear from your question what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: you have to share your staging/developing site so that we can i least have a look .